# Map a C# Dictionary to an array in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, dictionary

In my view model I have a dictionary that I want to evaluate in a jQuery function. I'm having a tough time mapping between the two languages.

View Model

```
public Dictionary<int, string> Collection { get; set; }
```

Script

```
$("#someButton").click(function () {
    var collection = {};
    var count = '@(Model.Collection.Count)' * 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        collection[i] = // Model.Collection[i]
    }
    ...
});
```

How do I either retrieve values by index directly from my view model's Collection property, or fill a local javascript array with that data so that I can operate on the copy in my function?

I've read a little about Knockout and Json.NET but I'm really hoping to avoid yet another dependency/learning curve in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON only support string as the key. So you could convert the `Dictionary<int, string`> to `Dictionary<string, string>` then put it in JS code by serializing it with JSON.NET. For example:

```
var collection = <%= Model.CollectionJson %>
```

which in the model:

```
public string CollectionJson {
    get {
        // correct API as @Superstringcheese suggested
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            Collection.ToDictionary(p => p.Key.ToString(), p => p.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe a method is a better choice over a property because in general a property implies a low cost calculation.

Comment: This was not working for me, but it led me to the realization that Json.NET is far more native than I thought. I ended up with: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Collection, Formatting.Indented);`

Comment: @Superstringcheese Thanks, I've corrected the API in the answer.